# Evaluating $ \lim _{x\to \:-\pi /6}\frac{\cos 2x+\sin x}{\sin 2x+\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Here's the problem:

> $$ \lim _{x\to \:-\frac{\pi }{6}}\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)}{\sin \left(2x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)}$$

I'm pretty sure I am supposed to use the notable limit

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

given the context of what I am studying. I've tried multiple ways and just kept getting stuck in indeterminations. Please help.

Comment: I doubt that the limit given in the title is of any use.

Comment: I guess you use L'Hospital?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any special limit here. Just note that
$$\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)}{\sin \left(2x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)}=\frac{1-2\sin^2(x)+\sin \left(x\right)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\cos(x)}=\frac{(2\sin(x)+1)(1-\sin(x))}{(2\sin(x)+1)\cos(x)}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: thank you! seems so simple now. but the way you factorized the numerator is to me not obvious at all. do you have any tips on how to do that?

Comment: The numerator is a quadratic polynomial with respect to $\sin x $

Comment: I feel dumb now :) thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Not that this method, in this case, is more efficient than factorization, but it can come handy in other situations.

Note that $\sin x=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ and, with
$$
\cos\alpha+\cos\beta=2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
the numerator becomes
$$
2\cos\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)
$$
Similarly, $\cos x=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$ and, with
$$
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta=2\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
$$
the denominator becomes
$$
2\sin\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)\cos\Bigl(\frac{3x}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)
$$
Thus you get, after factoring out $2\cos(3x/2-\pi/4)$,
$$
\lim_{x\to-\pi/6}\cot\Bigl(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigr)=\cot\frac{\pi}{6}
=\sqrt{3}
$$

Comment: +1 - I like this approach a lot more personally, because it relies only on familiar identities and the common factor is immediate, rather than the little bit of magic that it feels like the double-angle identities require.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative of the numerator and denominator so you get:
$$\lim _{x\to \:-\frac{\pi }{6}}\left(\frac{\cos \left(2x\right)+\sin \left(x\right)}{\sin \left(2x\right)+\cos \left(x\right)}\right)=\frac{\cos (-\frac{\pi }{6})-2 \sin (2 (-\frac{\pi }{6}))}{2 \cos (2 (-\frac{\pi }{6}))-\sin (-\frac{\pi }{6})}=\sqrt3$$